# How to get a list of column headers using Office Open XML SDK 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml-sdk

With OpenXML SDK 2.0 how do you get a list of column headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use MS Office OpenXML SDK 2.0, try [Koogra Excel BIFF/XLSX Reader Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/koogra/) instead wich will allow you to do this with 4 lines of code as such:

```
var r = worksheet.CellMap.FirstRow;
var row = worksheet.GetRow(r);
for (var c = worksheet.CellMap.FirstCol; c <= worksheet.CellMap.LastCol; ++c)
{
    Columns.Add(row.GetCell(c).GetFormattedValue());
}
```

`Columns` is a `List<string>`.

UPDATE: [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) is even better than Koogra and it is actively maintained so I switched to using that library in my projects and it is very fast and reliable in my experience...

Answer (score 4):

I don't want to copy-paste code here because it's quite large.

Here you can find example of what you need by using Open XML SDK 2.0: [How to: Get a Column Heading in a Spreadsheet Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc822064.aspx)

Provided example can be downloaded from MS site with all other examples related to Open XML 2.0. and MS Office: [Open XML SDK 2.0 Code Snippets for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=78bea298-a3f9-44cf-bde0-b4f30dc986df&displaylang=en)

Comment: Thanks, I checked all the How To examples and that one is about getting the column header of a given cell. Don't see how that code can be used to get a list of all the headers...

Comment: well, run this code in loop until you get to the column name = string.empty or null.

Comment: @HABJAN, I can do that but I think there must be a better way of doing this already baked into the SDK...

Comment: @kzen: contrary to popular belief, the SDK is not all that sophisticated. it's basically just a deserialized version of Open XML and doesn't actually have a lot of logic and rendering functionality like the object model. What Habjan suggested is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Otaku, thanks for that piece of info, I was using Net.SourceForge.Koogra.dll in my previous projects but thought that OpenXML SDK would be able to replace it... are you perhapse familiar with Koogra library and do you think I should stick to that instead of using OpenXML?

Comment: @kzen: I'm not familiar with Koogra, so I can't really comment on that. There are some Excel tools/apps on http://www.codeplex.com that are based on the SDK, but they go beyond it by trying to simulate the object model a bit. I'd explore those.